# Buscar todo los articulos cuyo nombre comience por los 5 caracteres del obtenido por la Id dada

Tags: mysql

Me dan un Id saco los 5 primeros caracteres y busco aquellos que empiecen por esas letras.
He llegado a esto

```
SELECT * FROM `producto` p WHERE p.nombre like (SELECT substring(nombre,1,5) FROM producto WHERE id=1);
```

Pero obviamete aqui no busca que empiece por si no que tenga esos 5 carateres le faltaria el % despues pero no se como meterlo
Me vale que busque por los 5 primero o por la primera palabra en cualuiera de los 2 casos no se como hacerlo

Comment: Ahi te busca un **campo** de la tabla producto que empiece con las cinco primeras letras de la variable nombre. Me parece que eso no es lo que estás buscando.

Comment: la subconsulta te da las 5 primeros caracteres del nombre por la ID que me dan. ahora necesito todo los producto que empiecen por esos 5 o todo lo que empiecen por la primera palabra. Obviemtne si estuviera bien no lo poseteo esta mal pero no se como hacer mas

Comment: Pero el `id=1` a que hace referencia?? Porque eso solo traería un único registro.

Comment: @unknow Como extra, usualmente en la práctica cuando el usuario busca algo tenemos que ignorar si es mayúscula o minúscula, acentos, etc. No siempre es así, usualmente lo es a menos que quieras buscar exactamente sin ignorar nada. Tener en cuenta esto puede que la búsqueda mejore para el usuario.

Comment: @OCHOA efectivamente como es un id es unico y solo trae un registro. hace referencia al id del producto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
SELECT * FROM `producto` p
  WHERE p.nombre
  like (SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(nombre,5), '%')
  FROM producto WHERE id=1);
```

Aquí solo agrego el `%` después de los 5 caracteres obtenidos con la función `LEFT()`, también uso `CONCAT()` para concatenar los primeros 5 caracteres del nombre del producto con el signo `%` para que se haga la búsqueda, así la consulta trae los registros que empiezan con los primeros 5 caracteres del nombre del producto que corresponden al id.

Answer (score 3):

El problema se resolvería de la siguiente forma:

```
SET @id_buscado = 'Categor'; #Ejemplo de parámetro
SELECT * 
FROM `producto` p 
WHERE p.nombre like concat(substring(@id_buscado,1,5),'%');
```

Esto te trae los productos que tengan las cinco primeras letras del nombre de producto del parámetro buscado.

Comment: Es que el paramtro es una ID un numero y lo que queremos son los productos que contengan las 5 primeras letras del nombre del producto con ese ID